# How do i fix the expected identifier error?

Tags: objective-c

I've been using [this website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//app)

to learn about Objective C and I'm trying to create an instance with `alloc` and `init` but i keep getting an error message from Xcode that says expected identifier. Here is my code:

```
NSObject *newObject = [[KDPPerson]int];
```

Comment: Did you import the header file for that class? And where is the call to `alloc`? And `init` is spelled `init`, not `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three things wrong with that line of code. It should be:

```
KDPPerson *newObject = [[KDPPerson alloc] init];
```

1. You were missing the call to `alloc`.
2. You spelled `init` incorrectly.
3. The variable `newObject` had the wrong type. Though using `NSObject` is technically correct, it's not very practical.

Also make sure you are importing `KDPPerson.h`.

Comment: Would I put this code in the implementation of the KDPPerson.h file or the main.m file

Comment: You put it wherever you need the object. Given your two choices it would be main.m.

Comment: I did what you said and input the code KDPPerson *newObject [ [KDPPerson alloc] init];.Now the error says "size of array has non-integer type KDPPerson.It also expects the symbol ] which I already put in.

Comment: Where's the equal sign?

Comment: Even with the equal sign the error says "Initializer element is not a compile time constant"

Comment: Where did you put the line of code? Sounds like it's in the wrong place.

Comment: I put it in the main M file as you recommended.Then I tryed it in the header file and it still did not work

Comment: If you put it in the main.m file, it must go inside the `main` function. I really suggest you find a good tutorial on the basics of Objective-C.